# What does AAA mean in nginx example of split_clients?

Tags: nginx, hash

On [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html) there is an example of `split_clients` directive:

```
split_clients "${remote_addr}AAA" $variant {
               0.5%               .one;
               2.0%               .two;
               *                  "";
}
```

In general I understand how this directive works, but I cannot understand what the purpose of `AAA` suffix is.

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"AAA" is just an ordinary string. IP address from `$remote_addr` variable and string "AAA" are concatenated and hashed into a 32-bit number. In case there are two requests from the same IP, this ensures that the value for the `$variant` variable will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but it is still not clear for me. if we omit `AAA` suffix, won't we get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, you will get the same behaviour. The string `AAA` is optional. My guess it that it's shown in the official documentation just to make an example that you can concatenate various variables and strings, as to some people it may be useful.

Comment: @Curious Changing the string `AAA` to something else, will cause the hashes to be completely different, putting different visitors into the test groups.